# Custom combobox doesn't save Item Collection in Form1.designer.cs

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, custom-component, itemcollection

I was trying to create a custom combobox that inherited from ComboBox, but I've experienced some difficulties with the DropDownBox style. I've found some code for a custom combo box on codeproject.com, and I enhanced it a bit because the combobox had some problems.

I only have 1 problem at the momemnt. When I add items in the Items collection, the items is not there at runtime, because they are not saved in the Form1.designed.cs file (cheetahComboBox1.Items.AddRange) like with a normal combobox.  Do I miss something? Is there an attribute that I should add?

Update: Sorry I had to truncate the source because of length, I've excluded some of the non-esential code that is not part of the Items collection
Here is the source for the combobox:

```
namespace Cheetah.UI.Custom
{
    public class CheetahComboBox : ListControl
    {
        private bool hovered = false;
        private bool pressed = false;
        private bool resize = false;

        private Color _backColor = Color.Black;
        private Color _foreColor = Color.Yellow;
        private Color _bordercolor = Color.Gray;

        private int _dropDownHeight = 200;
        private int _dropDownWidth = 0;
        private int _maxDropDownItems = 8;

        private int _selectedIndex = -1;

        private bool _isDroppedDown = false;
        private bool _popupclosedcalled = false;

        private ComboBoxStyle _dropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

        private Rectangle rectBtn = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);
        private Rectangle rectContent = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);

        private ToolStripControlHost _controlHost;
        private ListBox _listBox;
        private ToolStripDropDown _popupControl;
        private TextBox _textBox;

        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return _bordercolor; }
            set { _bordercolor = value; Invalidate(true); }
        }

        public int DropDownHeight
        {
            get { return _dropDownHeight; }
            set { _dropDownHeight = value; }
        }

        [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing")]
        public ListBox.ObjectCollection Items
        {
            get { return _listBox.Items; }
        }

        public override Color ForeColor
        {
            get
            {
                return base.ForeColor;
            }
            set
            {
                base.ForeColor = value;
                _listBox.ForeColor = value;
                _textBox.ForeColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public ComboBoxStyle DropDownStyle
        {
            get { return _dropDownStyle; }
            set 
            { 
                _dropDownStyle = value; 

                if (_dropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)
                {
                    if (_listBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
                    {
                        _textBox.Text = "";
                        base.Text = "";
                    }
                    _textBox.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    _textBox.Visible = true;
                }
                Invalidate(true);
            }
        }

        public new Color BackColor
        {
            get { return _backColor; }
            set 
            { 
                this._backColor = value;
                _textBox.BackColor = value;
                _listBox.BackColor = value;
                Invalidate(true);
            }
        }

        public bool IsDroppedDown
        {
            get { return _isDroppedDown; }
            set 
            {
                if (_isDroppedDown == true && value == false )
                {
                    if (_popupControl.IsDropDown)
                    {
                        _popupControl.Close();
                    }
                }

                _isDroppedDown = value;

                if (_isDroppedDown)
                {
                    _controlHost.Control.Width = _dropDownWidth;

                    _listBox.Refresh();

                    if (_listBox.Items.Count > 0) 
                    {
                        int h = 0;
                        int i = 0;
                        int maxItemHeight = 0;
                        int highestItemHeight = 0;
                        foreach(object item in _listBox.Items)
                        {
                            int itHeight = _listBox.GetItemHeight(i);
                            if (highestItemHeight < itHeight) 
                            {
                                highestItemHeight = itHeight;
                            }
                            h = h + itHeight;
                            if (i <= (_maxDropDownItems - 1)) 
                            {
                                maxItemHeight = h;
                            }
                            i = i + 1;
                        }

                        if (maxItemHeight > _dropDownHeight)
                            _listBox.Height = _dropDownHeight + 3;
                        else
                        {
                            if (maxItemHeight > highestItemHeight )
                                _listBox.Height = maxItemHeight + 3;
                            else
                                _listBox.Height = highestItemHeight + 3;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _listBox.Height = 15;
                    }

                    _popupControl.Show(this, CalculateDropPosition(), ToolStripDropDownDirection.BelowRight);
                }

                Invalidate();
                if (_isDroppedDown)
                    OnDroppedDown(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public CheetahComboBox()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ContainerControl, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);

            base.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

            this.Height = 21;
            this.Width = 95;

            this.SuspendLayout();

            _textBox = new TextBox();
            _textBox.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            _textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 4);
            _textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 13);
            _textBox.TabIndex = 0;
            _textBox.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            _textBox.BackColor = Color.Black;
            _textBox.WordWrap = false;
            _textBox.Margin = new Padding(0);
            _textBox.Padding = new Padding(0);
            _textBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            this.Controls.Add(_textBox);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

            AdjustControls();

            _listBox = new ListBox();
            _listBox.IntegralHeight = true;
            _listBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            _listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
            _listBox.BindingContext = new BindingContext();

            _controlHost = new ToolStripControlHost(_listBox);
            _controlHost.Padding = new Padding(0);
            _controlHost.Margin = new Padding(0);
            _controlHost.AutoSize = false;

            _popupControl = new ToolStripDropDown();
            _popupControl.Padding = new Padding(0);
            _popupControl.Margin = new Padding(0);
            _popupControl.AutoSize = true;
            _popupControl.DropShadowEnabled = false;
            _popupControl.Items.Add(_controlHost);

            _dropDownWidth = this.Width;

            _listBox.MeasureItem += new MeasureItemEventHandler(_listBox_MeasureItem);
            _listBox.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(_listBox_DrawItem);
            _listBox.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(_listBox_MouseClick);
            _listBox.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(_listBox_MouseMove);

            _popupControl.Closed += new ToolStripDropDownClosedEventHandler(_popupControl_Closed);

            _textBox.Resize += new EventHandler(_textBox_Resize);
            _textBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(_textBox_TextChanged);
        }

        protected override void OnDisplayMemberChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            _listBox.DisplayMember = this.DisplayMember;
            this.SelectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
            base.OnDisplayMemberChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate(true);
            base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnForeColorChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            _textBox.ForeColor = this.ForeColor;
            base.OnForeColorChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnFormatInfoChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            _listBox.FormatInfo = this.FormatInfo;
            base.OnFormatInfoChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnFormatStringChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            _listBox.FormatString = this.FormatString;
            base.OnFormatStringChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnFormattingEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            _listBox.FormattingEnabled = this.FormattingEnabled;
            base.OnFormattingEnabledChanged(e);
        }

        public override Font Font
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Font;
            }
            set
            {
                resize = true;
                _textBox.Font = value;
                base.Font = value;
                Invalidate(true);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Control.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Control_MouseDown);
            e.Control.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(Control_MouseEnter);
            e.Control.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(Control_MouseLeave);
            e.Control.GotFocus += new EventHandler(Control_GotFocus);
            e.Control.LostFocus += new EventHandler(Control_LostFocus);
            base.OnControlAdded(e);
        }        

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            hovered = true;
            this.Invalidate(true);
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle).Contains(MousePosition))
            {
                hovered = false;
                Invalidate(true);
            }

            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_popupclosedcalled)
            {
                _popupclosedcalled = false;
                return;
            }
            _textBox.Focus();
            if ((this.RectangleToScreen(rectBtn).Contains(MousePosition) || (DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)))
            {
                pressed = true;
                this.Invalidate(true);
                if (this.IsDroppedDown) 
                {
                    this.IsDroppedDown = false;
                }
                this.IsDroppedDown = true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            pressed = false;

            if (! this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle).Contains(MousePosition) )
                hovered = false;
            else
                hovered = true;

            Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Delta < 0)
                this.SelectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex + 1;
            else if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                if (this.SelectedIndex > 0)
                    this.SelectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex - 1;
            }

            base.OnMouseWheel(e);
        }

        protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate(true);
            base.OnGotFocus(e);
        }

        protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.ContainsFocus)
            {
                Invalidate();
            }

            base.OnLostFocus(e);
        }

        protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if(SelectedIndexChanged!=null)
                SelectedIndexChanged(this, e);

            base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnValueMemberChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            _listBox.ValueMember = this.ValueMember;
            this.SelectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
            base.OnValueMemberChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            //draw component background
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), Rectangle.FromLTRB(0, 0, Width, Height));

            //text
            if (DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)
            {
                StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

                Rectangle rectText = _textBox.Bounds;
                rectText.Offset(-3, 0);

                SolidBrush foreBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor);
                if (Enabled)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(_textBox.Text, this.Font, foreBrush, rectText.Location);
                }
                //else
                //{
                //    ControlPaint.DrawStringDisabled(e.Graphics, _textBox.Text, Font, BackColor, rectText, sf);
                //}
            }

            //content border
            Rectangle rectCont = rectContent;
            rectCont.X += 1;
            rectCont.Y += 1;
            rectCont.Width -= 3;
            rectCont.Height -= 3;
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(_bordercolor), Rectangle.FromLTRB(1, 1, Width - 2, Height - 2));

            //                    if (this.SelectedIndex >= 0 && DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)
            //                        e.Graphics.DrawString(Items[this.SelectedIndex].ToString(), this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), new PointF(3, 3));
            //                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(FUpButtonPicture, Rectangle.FromLTRB(Width - 17, 4, Width - 3, Height - 4));

            //button border
            Rectangle rectButton = rectBtn;
            rectButton.X += 1;
            rectButton.Y += 1;
            rectButton.Width -= 3;
            rectButton.Height -= 3;
            if (IsDroppedDown)
            {
                if (FDownButtonPicture != null)
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(FDownButtonPicture, Rectangle.FromLTRB(Width - 17, 4, Width - 3, Height - 4));
                else
                    DrawButtonAndGlimph(e);
            }
            else
                if (FUpButtonPicture != null)
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(FUpButtonPicture, Rectangle.FromLTRB(Width - 17, 4, Width - 3, Height - 4));
                else
                    DrawButtonAndGlimph(e);

            e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
        }

        public override int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedIndex; }
            set 
            { 
                if(_listBox != null)
                {
                    if (_listBox.Items.Count == 0)
                        return;

                    if ((this.DataSource != null) && value == -1)
                        return;

                    if (value <= (_listBox.Items.Count - 1) && value >= -1)
                    {
                        _listBox.SelectedIndex = value;
                        _selectedIndex = value;
                        //SelectedItem = _listBox.SelectedItem;
                        _textBox.Text = _listBox.GetItemText(_listBox.SelectedItem);
                        base.Text = _textBox.Text;
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _textBox.Text = "";
                        base.Text = "";
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                    Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _listBox.SelectedItem;  }
            set 
            { 
                _listBox.SelectedItem = value;
                this.SelectedIndex = _listBox.SelectedIndex;
                if (SelectedIndex >= 0)
                    _textBox.Text = _listBox.Items[SelectedIndex].ToString();
                else
                    _textBox.Text = "";
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public new object SelectedValue
        {
            get { return base.SelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                base.SelectedValue = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void RefreshItem(int index)
        {
            //throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }

        protected override void SetItemsCore(IList items)
        {
        }

        void Control_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnLostFocus(e);
        }

        void Control_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnGotFocus(e);
        }

        void Control_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnMouseLeave(e);
        }

        void Control_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnMouseEnter(e);
        }

        void Control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            OnMouseDown(e);
        }

        void _listBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < (_listBox.Items.Count); i++)
            {
                if (_listBox.GetItemRectangle(i).Contains(_listBox.PointToClient(MousePosition)))
                {
                    _listBox.SelectedIndex = i;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        void _listBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_listBox.Items.Count == 0)
                return;
            if (_listBox.SelectedItems.Count != 1)
                return;

            this.SelectedIndex = _listBox.SelectedIndex;

            if (DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)
            {
                this.Invalidate(true);
            }

            IsDroppedDown = false;
        }

        void _popupControl_Closed(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            _isDroppedDown = false;
            _popupclosedcalled = true;
            pressed = false;
            if (!this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle).Contains(MousePosition))
            {
                hovered = false;
            }
            Invalidate(true);
        }

        void _textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnTextChanged(e);
        }

        private void AdjustControls()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();

            resize = true;
            _textBox.Top = 4;
            _textBox.Left = 5;
            this.Height = _textBox.Top + _textBox.Height + _textBox.Top;

            rectBtn = new Rectangle(this.ClientRectangle.Width - 18, this.ClientRectangle.Top, 18, _textBox.Height + 2 * _textBox.Top);

            _textBox.Width = rectBtn.Left - 1 - _textBox.Left;

            rectContent = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Left, ClientRectangle.Top,
                ClientRectangle.Width, _textBox.Height + 2 * _textBox.Top);

            this.ResumeLayout();

            Invalidate(true);
        }

        public virtual void OnDroppedDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DroppedDown != null)
            {
                DroppedDown(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I am new to C#, so forgive me that I don't know these noob stuff yet. Anyway, here is the answer:

Add the DesignerSerializationVisibility attribute above the Items property, and make sure that System.Design is added to references.

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
```

Comment: Serialize the property is the correct terminology. As I said, new to this. A lot of the terminology I still have to familiar myself with :)